# Azure cosmos db migration tool error occurred while sending the request

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I'm not able to connect to Azure cosmos migration tool,
getting an error like : An error occurred while sending the request.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and provide more details. It looks like you're trying to verify the connection string. Please do not provide the details in comments.

Comment: Did you follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data) to use the migration tool? If you did, could you pls tell us which step you met the error? I think more details are needed for others to reproduce the error if they haven't met this error before.

Comment: I have tried to add the connection string and tried to verify but for me, it gives an error, and for other guys the same string works.

Comment: @dadananjesha I've add some details on my test and if it doesn't match your situation, perhaps you can provide more details so that we can troubleshot it better with you. Thanks for your response.

Comment: I am getting the same error, please help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but when I tried to reproduce your error in my side, I found that only I used a wrong AccountEndpoint in my connection string I would meet this error message. Whether or not I used a serverless database, whether or not I set network policy, these situation all not return error like yours. So my suggestion is, maybe you can add more details on your db, import file type, etc. And you can also check your connection string.

Here's my conncention string:

Go to cosmosdb->Keys->copy primary connection string->append `Database=YourDatabaseName`

AccountEndpoint=https://xxx.documents.azure.com:443/;AccountKey=xxx;Database=ToDoList

[image]
[image]

Comment: I have used the correct endpoint and it's working for others but not for me. Don't know what is the issue.

Comment: I did the test to establish firewall but it didn't lead to your error. Did you copy the PRIMARY CONNECTION STRING from the place where I mentioned above? And have you tried to create another new cosmosdb to rule out the possibility of database error or some wrong configurations of the instance?

Comment: I have never had this issue before, Sunddely I am getting this issue and help will be much appreciated